# How to exclude order and customer data whilst migrating from Magento 1 to Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool

How do I skip order and customer data whilst migrating from Magento 1 to magento 2?

Magento 1 version : **1.9.2.4**

Magento 2 version : **2.3.4**

Answer (score 2):

First backup your magento 2 db.

In the config.xml file  for data step replace the following code

```
<steps mode="data">
        <step title="Map Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
```

Next,

> In data.php under `src/Migration/Step/Map/Data.php`
>   replace the line  `$sourceDocuments = $this->source->getDocumentList();` 
>   with

```
$sourceDocuments =
    [
        'catalog_product_bundle_option',
        'catalog_product_bundle_option_value',
        'catalog_product_bundle_price_index',
        'catalog_product_bundle_selection',
        'catalog_product_bundle_selection_price',
        'catalog_product_bundle_stock_index',
        'catalog_product_enabled_index',
        'catalog_product_entity',
        'catalog_product_entity_datetime',
        'catalog_product_entity_decimal',
        'catalog_product_entity_gallery',
        'catalog_product_entity_group_price',
        'catalog_product_entity_int',
        'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery',
        'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value',
        'catalog_product_entity_text',
        'catalog_product_entity_tier_price',
        'catalog_product_entity_varchar',
        'catalog_product_link',
        'catalog_product_link_attribute',
        'catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal',
        'catalog_product_link_attribute_int',
        'catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar',
        'catalog_product_link_type',
        'catalog_product_option',
        'catalog_product_option_price',
        'catalog_product_option_title',
        'catalog_product_option_type_price',
        'catalog_product_option_type_title',
        'catalog_product_option_type_value',
        'catalog_product_relation',
        'catalog_product_website',        
    ]
```

Migrate the data with reset

products only migrated